# Windows 8 & Eclipse ADT Plugin

Tags: eclipse, plugins, windows-8, adt

If I try to Install a new plugin (ADT Plugin), with the Eclipse feature on Help section, It won't advance from "Calculating requirements and dependencies. Both title and link are correct, because I've already tried on 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running Eclipse as Administrator.

Comment: please extend your answer as to what you think is the problem and how running Eclipse might help. as far as I know eclipse doesn't need administrative privileges to update its components.

Comment: andr is probably right.  Running eclipse as administrator gave me the same results.